# How do I start a Vertx 3 Verticle from a main method?

Tags: java, vertx3

How do I start a Verx 3 Verticle from a main method? I have figured out how to start it from unit tests and the getting started [guide](http://vertx.io/blog/my-first-vert-x-3-application/) explains how to build a fat jar. But how do I simply start it from a main method for the purpose of debugging, profiling etc?

Answer (score 12):

Simply do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(MyVerticle.class.getName());
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(new MyVerticle());
}
```

EDIT: As suggested by Will, here is an example which takes the result into consideration and blocks the main thread until it succeeds:

```
BlockingQueue<AsyncResult<String>> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(new Application(), q::offer);
AsyncResult<String> result = q.take();
if (result.failed()) {
    throw new RuntimeException(result.cause());
}
```

Comment: It's always worth using the overloaded method that takes a handler with the result. Otherwise you won't know if your Verticle failed to start.

Comment: @Will: Thanks, added an example which takes this into consideration.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Can you be more clear about `result.cause()`? I can't see where it's coming from.

Comment: @thisdotvoid good catch. `result` should be what `q.take()` returns, which is a Vertx AsyncResult. I'll edit.

Comment: This answer leaves out the process of launching with the cmd args, such as launching in a cluster or specifying a conf.